# HTC One M8 - Do Not Disturb still plays sounds in Videos and Music. Any total sounds off option?

Tags: audio, htc, 6.0-marshmallow, volume

Do Not Disturb>On

Message displayed:

> This turns off all sounds and vibrations, including from alarms,
>   music, video and games.

If I turn on this mode, go to Youtube (or any website with a video) the sound is still on.

Is there a way of simply disabling all sounds from this phone? This can be a problem E.g. If I browse to a news website with an auto play video, the sounds can start up

Screenshot (as requested) of the Message and Do Not Disturb setting
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Firelord Image of the message added:-)